# horizontal unordered list

Tags: html, css

I can do this in 5 seconds with a table but I'm trying to avoid it by using CSS, looks fine in FF but problem is it doesn't work in IE (the second li appears underneath the first li)

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px">
   <li style="width:120px; display:table-cell; padding: 1px;"><?=$m['make']?></li>
   <li style="width:30px; display:table-cell;  padding: 1px;"><input id="changemanufacturer" type="checkbox"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using IE7 or IE8, make sure your DOCTYPE is present so that its not rendering in quirks mode.

Using the HTML4 Strict or HTML5 DOCTYPES worked for me in IE8

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px"> 
        <li style="width:120px; display:table-cell; padding:1px;">asdf</li> 
        <li style="width:30px; display:table-cell; padding: 1px;">
        <input id="changemanufacturer"  type="checkbox">
        </li>
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

HTML5: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 10):

Don't use table cell.  Do:

```
<li style="width:120px; display:inline; float:left;">Boo!</li>
```

Of course you should have your CSS external but I'll assume it's just to simplify the question.

Comment: It's the display:inline that's your friend.

Comment: Which one is the key to the style, `display:inline` or `float:left`? I found both of them works in Chrome.